# no audio data from PC send to STM32F4 audio class USB

Tags: audio, usb, stm32f4discovery, stm32cubemx

I'm working in an audio project. We use stm32f407 like a USB audio device to get audio data from PC then send out by I2S module. We are using stm32f4 Discovery kit and STM32cubeMX. After generate code by following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NnIum2hAWg), i change nothing and flash to Kit; my PC identifies that STM Audio device but there isn't any data send to my kit when play music, except MuteCMD . My question is:

- i don't know which function is callback when data stream from PC to Kit.
- why PC identifies that my kit is an audio output device but the callback of volume control isn't called when I config volume on PC and there isn't any data of music send to my device. The only one mute control callback function is called when i mute the PC.

this is my config in STM32cubeMX

pinout config figure
[image: pinout config figure]

USB device config figure 1
[image: USB device config figure 1]

USB device config figure 2
[image: USB device config figure 2]

USB device config figure 3
[image: USB device config figure 3]

PC identifies AUDIO device figure
[image: PC identifies AUDIO device figure]

choosing PC's audio output device figure
[image: choosing PC's audio output device figure]

fail to play test tone figure
[image: fail to play test tone figure]

Answer (score 1):

I had exact same problem.
My project is generated from STM32Cube.
Windows recognizes the F7-DISCO board as sound card but failed to play test sounds.

I changed **USBD_AUDIO_FREQ to 48000** and **PID to 0x5730** (22320 in decimal).
And then everything works fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked for me as well. I deduced the same thing about the sample rate being an issue. If you're still out there do you know why changing the PID has an effect?

Answer (score 0):

You should set USBD_AUDIO_FREQ to 22050 (or 44100, or 11025). Your value is 22100 and it seems like Windows or built-in audio drivers can't use that frequency.